# Retrieving the last message between two users

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

Considering the schema on this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b9528/2), I'm trying to retrieve the last message between two users with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("user_id") *
FROM
(
  (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON ("user_id")
    "id",
    "recipient_id" AS "user_id",
    "body",
    "read",
    "created_at"
  FROM "messages"
  WHERE "sender_id" = 1
  ORDER BY "user_id", "created_at" DESC
  )

  UNION ALL

  (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON ("user_id")
    "id",
    "sender_id" AS "user_id",
    "body",
    "read",
    "created_at"
  FROM "messages"
  WHERE "recipient_id" = 1
  ORDER BY "user_id", "created_at" DESC
  )
) AS "messages"
INNER JOIN "users" ON ("users"."id" = "messages"."user_id")
ORDER BY "user_id", "messages"."created_at" DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

It works as intended and is pretty fast when the given user doesn't have too much messages, but when the number of messages grow and furthermore if the message body is large, the execution time becomes much slower. Analyzing the execution plan looks that the 'bottleneck' is on the ORDER BY of that two subqueries because it has to sort about 10k of rows in memory.

After struggling with this query for 5 hours I've been unable to find a faster way to achieve what I want. I've tried to add an index on (sender_id, created_at DESC) and (recipient_id, created_at DESC) but obviously it doesn't seem to help.

So, what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

PS: This is the execution plan on the implementation: http://explain.depesz.com/s/0aE

Comment: Your question wording confused me, you say "between two users", but it appears you mean to say messages "received or sent by a given user"?

Comment: And are you hoping to get the last (one) message, or the last 20 messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two tips:

- remove ORDER BY clause from subqueries in UNION, as you have order clause on UNION.
- move `body`, `read`, `username`, `name` outside the main query and join them to the result in a new *wrapper* query.

Sorry for removing doublequotes ;)

```
SELECT s.id, user_id, body, read, s.created_at, username, name
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) *
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) id, recipient_id AS user_id, created_at
            FROM messages
            WHERE sender_id = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) id, sender_id AS user_id, created_at
            FROM messages
            WHERE recipient_id = 1
        ) s
    ORDER BY user_id, created_at DESC
    LIMIT 20
    ) s
JOIN users u ON (u.id = s.user_id)
JOIN messages m ON (m.id = s.id)
```

Comment: This! Thank you very much, it works like a charm. Don't worry about the double quotes, they were added by the orm. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are unioning two huge queries, sorting the union by a column that is part of each subquery, and then taking only the first 20 results. This would most likely be quicker if you sort and limit each subquery in the same way you will sort and limit their union.

This is probably unrelated to the performance, but, I don't see the point of ordering and selecting `DISTINCT ON` the `"user_id"` columns, when those columns are all going to be a single value (the id of the user you're searching for). Am I missing something?

So I think something like this should be much faster when there are many messages:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  (
  SELECT
    -- ...
  ORDER BY "created_at" DESC
  LIMIT 20
  )
  UNION ALL
  (
  SELECT
    -- ...
  ORDER BY "created_at" DESC
  LIMIT 20
  )
) AS "messages"
INNER JOIN -- ...
ORDER BY "messages"."created_at" DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

By limiting each subquery to the most recent 20 messages, you know that in the resulting (up to) 40 messages, you have the most recent 20 of them. All of them could have been in one subquery, or all in the other, or some in each.